# Configure SQL Connection with jdbc - vagrant

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, jdbc, vagrant

I have a vagrant server:

```
postgres@precise32:/home/vagrant/teste/pg-hostname-master$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  
          inet addr:33.33.33.33  Bcast:33.33.33.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
```

The port is:

```
name       | port
setting    | 5432
```

My question is, what is the correct data to use jdbc?

I already tried:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test

jdbc:postgresql://33.33.33.33:5432/test

jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/test
```

None of these works.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

**Update:**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1020/postgres
```

In `postgresql.conf`

```
Listen_adresses = '*'
```

vagrant log

```
C:\Users\xx>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
[default] Machine booted and ready!
[default] Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant
[default] VM already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use `--provision` to force it
```

---

Basically, I need to know how can I set a remote db connection between vagrant (ubuntu) and windows desktop. Both running in the same desktop.

Comment: What makes you think it's running PostgreSQL? `netstat -ltnp`, `ps -ef |grep postgres` ? If it's running PostgreSQL, what is `listen_addresses` set to in `postgresql.conf` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger Listen_adresses = '*'

Comment: @CraigRinger And, question updated, thanks

Comment: Local firewall rules?

Comment: @CraigRinger I don't have firewall in windows or ubuntu. But what is the supposed host to connect to database based in the info that i am providing?

Comment: Tried `jdbc:postgresql://10.0.2.15:5432/test`? Are your code running on the same server or another and if so are they on the same network?

Comment: What VM (provider) are you using? Can you connect to postgresql within the VM (eg using psql command)? Is networking using forwarded ports or internal network or?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Not working, Same server.

Comment: @harmic virtualbox. I can use postgresql CLI with putty for example. My setup is basic, a desktop with windows7+virtual box and vagrant.

Comment: Can you add or link a copy of your vagrantfile? Particularly the part relating to networking. I do not think networking is correctly set up in your VM

Comment: @harmic http://sharetext.org/xqSZ thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a disclaimer - I have used virtualbox and postgresql quite a lot, but I have not used vagrant, so advice I can give about that is limited.

From your description and the information in the comments, I think your problem is related to network connectivity between the VM and the host environment.

Virtualbox supports a few different network emulations - eg NAT, Bridged, Internal Network, Host-only. When using vagrant, vagrant will attempt to administer the VM to align to the configuration in the 'vagrantfile'.

The 'NAT' adapter uses a simulated NAT. It is a bit like having the VM on the inside of a private network with a router connecting it to the internet. You can make outgoing connections via the NAT interface but not incoming connections, unless you set up port forwarding. Your vagrant log file says this:

```
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
```

indicating that port 2222 is being forwarded to port 22 on the VM (at least that is how I interpret this printout). This would allow you to connect to the VM via SSH from a client such as putty running in the windows environment. Virtualbox listens on port 22 on the loopback adaptor (127.0.0.1) in the Windows environment, forwarding any connections to the NAT adaptor in the VM.

Your ifconfig shows two ethernet adapters (aside from the loopback) - one configured for address 10.0.2.15 and the other for 33.33.33.33.

10.0.2.15 is the address used by the NAT adaptor.

33.33.33.33 seems to have been configured by the following lines in your vagrantfile:

```
# Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
# using a specific IP.
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "33.33.33.33"
```

So, this is configuring an internal network, probably using a 'host-only' adaptor in virtualbox. The problem is, I suspect that the IP address 33.33.33.33 is not valid for such a network. The default internal network in virtualbox is set up for the network 192.168.56.0/24.

Here are the steps I recommend you follow to resolve this:

1. Before doing anything else, double check that you can establish a connection to the postgresql server using:

   ```
    su - postgres
    psql -h 127.0.0.1 template1
   ```

   from a shell on the VM (ie. either log in via ssh or using the VM console). This ensures that postgresql is running and accepting connections from network interfaces.
2. Confirm that the Virtualbox VM is configured for a host-only adaptor as 'Adaptor 2'. From the virtualbox GUI, select VM -> settings -> Network -> Adaptor 2. It should say 'Host-only adaptor'. Note the name of the adaptor.
3. Check the configuration of the host only network. From the Virtualbox GUI, File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-Only Networks -> double click the named network from step 1. Note the IPv4 address and netmask. The defaults for that are 192.168.56.0 and 255.255.255.0.

   You should be using a private network.
4. In your vagrantfile, change the ip address to one that is in the range of the network seen in step 2 - eg. 192.168.56.10. Then restart vagrant using whatever command is needed to get it to reconfigure the VM.
5. Confirm that you can ping the address you have used from the windows command prompt. Also that you can connect the VM using an SSH client on the windows side, using the same address.
6. If all of that has worked, you should be able to connect to the postgresql server using `jdbc:postgresql://{ipaddr}:5432/test` where {ipaddr} is the ip address you used in step 3,4.

Answer (score 0):

First check that you don't have any other VMs running with the same IP. `vagrant halt` that machine and try to ping "33.33.33.33". It shouldn't respond. (By the way, 33.33.33.x is a public network that somebody own, you should use a [private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) like 192.168.33.x.)

Also some VPN software can mess up the routing. Are you running any?

The localhost addresses won't work from host, unless you set [port forwarding](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/networking/forwarded_ports.html):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 5432, host: 5432
end
```

Comment: Not responding if i do vagrant halt, so is working as expected. The port forwarding didn't work. Same error. No VPN.

Comment: Can you connect to the postgres server from the guest? And did you try netcat/telnet?